# How can I make Go return the same value for a pixel as what it was set to?

Tags: go

Setting and getting pixels in Go images works in a way that surprised me:

```
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    img := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 1, 1))
    c := color.RGBA{R: 7}
    img.SetRGBA(0, 0, c)
    R, _, _, _ := img.At(0, 0).RGBA()
    if R != uint32(c.R) {
        log.Fatalf("fetched red is %d, want %d", R, uint32(c.R))
    }
    log.Printf("OK")
}
```

This outputs "2009/11/10 23:00:00 fetched red is 1799, want 7". Why does it do that and how can I make it work as expected?

Comment: `RGBA()` returns components scaled between `0` and `0xffff`, and not the `color.RGBA` type. If you look at the red component of `c` via `c.RGBA()`, you get the same value.

Comment: Always consult the documentation about the involved types and read the documentation: Go's documentation is helpful, readable and important.